# Newline "\n" in TextField java

Tags: java, textfield

I am building string ( 3 different objects ) and at the end of string I put  a newline
when I print in console I get what expected but when I use setText in the textfield I get one line displayed, Is there a way to get the newline in textfield?

```
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
          tx +=   "\n"+el.getnombre() + " " +other+"\n";  
    System.out.println(tx);
    textfield.setText(tx);
```

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of `tx += ...` - if `itr.hasAWholeBunch()` then building `tx` will be very slow.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

JTextField or TextField (not sure which you're using) are for single lines only.  If you want a basic multiline text display and you're using Swing, then use a JTextArea.  If you're not using Swing, then please tell us which GUI library you are using as this is an important detail that your question should mention.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, use `JTextArea` instead of `JTextField`.
And there either use `JTextArea.append(String text)`, or use `JTextArea.setText(String text)`.

1. Option: Appends the given text to the end of the document.
   This will add text on to the end of your `JTextArea`.
2. Option: `getText()` to get the text from the `JTextArea`, then manipulate the String, then use `setText(String text)` to set the text of the `JTextArea` to be the new String.

To set the text in a newline you need to add "\n" at the end of your String.
Following code shows the second option:

```
String oldlines = VisualizeArea.getText(); 
String newline = "your new line"
VisualizeArea.setText(oldlines + "\n" + newline);
```