# How to append a newline to StringBuilder? append(“\n”) or append(System.getProperty("line.separator")) doesnt works

Tags: java, newline, stringbuilder

I am doing a java program in Netbeans on windows os. I have a StringBuilder object

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

I have to append newline to it. I have tried

```
builder.append(“\n”);   
builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
```

It works when am displaying the output through System.out.println(builder);
But none of them works when am displaying it to a jTextField. What is the problem

Comment: You need a `JTextArea` not a `JTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the following post: [Newline "\n" in TextField java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453925/newline-n-in-textfield-java)

> JTextField or TextField (not sure which you're using) are for single lines only. If you want a basic multiline text display and you're using Swing, then use a JTextArea. If you're not using Swing, then please tell us which GUI library you are using as this is an important detail that your question should mention.